# Customising bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an application that I'd like to used Bootstrap in. However, I would like some customisitions with regards to colors, sizes, etc.

Currently, I'm forking Bootstrap, building it myself with my own customizations. This works, obviously, but also has some obvious downsides:

- When a new version of Bootstrap comes out, I have to merge manually
- I can't use an external CDN with hosted standard js/css
- Total build time of the project rises greatly

I'm looking for a better way that doesn't suffer from these downsides. Are there any standard extension points that I can plug in to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I've developed a couple projects using Bootstrap and my solution is using my own CSS which implements my customizations overriding certain properties of the Bootstrap classes.

Also, in Bootstrap website there's a customization option that allows you to generate your own customized Bootstrap library. I haven't tested it yet, but it looks that it may bewhat you're looking for. [Here's the link](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)